# When should I add self before an object? is it save to always add it for view level objects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Yesterday I found that I needed to add self to an object as it was causing a problem.

I've been adding self to a few other objects today, it compiles and seems to work fine when I do. But I'm wondering if maybe I shouldn't be always adding self ?

Comment: what was the problem when you used `self`?

Comment: I was getting NSString out of scope, I needed to use the self accessor to retain my variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an ivar that is backing a property `myFoo`, then `self.myFoor` will use the property, whereas `myFoo` directly will not.
For example with this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyClass myFoo;
```

`self.myFoo = temp;` will retain temp
`myFoo = temp;` will **not** retain temp

Comment: When you say retain, it does the myVar within the class.